# Few lines of Htaccess to Nginx Convert

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, converters

I tried the online converters and none of them worked.

How can I convert the below lines of htaccess to nginx rule. I was only able to convert one line from the below code. I don't even know whether its right or wrong.

My nginx Conf

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
     }
  
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
```

This is code I want to convert to nginx.

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # cors
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>

# Hide a specific file
<Files .env>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

These are the only lines I was able to convert.

```
# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

To

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

Still I have doubt in the above nginx rule whether it should contain **?$args** before the colon mark or not?

Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I used an AI to assist in this conversion. Curious to see how it did.

```
# cors
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

# gzip
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

# cache
fastcgi_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache:10m max_size=10g inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;

# security
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer";
add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none";

# php
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
```

Comment: "an AI"?! lol, it needs more training! Apart from the very first directive (although it has no _context_), this isn't even in the right ballpark!?

Comment: It's not working.